# Dynamic button - Runtime error 1004 - Unable to get the Buttons property of the Worksheet class

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm getting "Runtime error 1004 - Unable to get the Buttons property of the Worksheet class" and it's coming from line near the bottom `Set b = Worksheets("Form").Buttons(Application.Caller) 'references button`.

I'm basically trying to copy the data in the column next to a dynamic button that appears next to the fully expanded fields of a pivot table. I've got the buttons appearing fine, I just need them to copy the data in the adjacent cell to a list in another sheet when that particular button is clicked.

```
Sub buttonGenerator()

Dim btn As Button
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveSheet.Buttons.Delete
Dim t As Range
Dim size As Long

size = Worksheets("Form").PivotTables("Pivottable1").TableRange2.Rows.Count 'returns number of rows in expanding pivot table

For i = 2 To size Step 1 'cycles through from row 2 to last row of pivot table
    If Not IsEmpty(Worksheets("Form").Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 4))) Then 'only shows button if last col of pivot table has data
      Set t = Worksheets("Form").Range(Cells(i, 5), Cells(i, 5))
      Set btn = Worksheets("Form").Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
      With btn
        .OnAction = "btnS" 'call btnS subroutine
        .Caption = "Button" & i 'button label
        .Name = "Button" & i 'button name
        End With
    End If

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub


Public Sub btnS()

Dim b As Object
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer

Set b = Worksheets("Form").Buttons(Application.Caller) 'references button
With b.TopLeftCell 'returns row and col of button pushed
r = .row
c = .col
End With

origin = Range(r, c)
dest = Worksheets("Form Output").Range(Cells(1, 1))
dest.Value = origin.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines:

```
 Option Explicit      ' :)
 Dim origin As Range
 Dim dest As Range
```

Correct these lines:

```
 c = .colUMN
 ...
 SET origin = Worksheets("Form").Cells(r, c)
 SET dest = Worksheets("Form Output").Cells(1, 1)
```

Some advice: you can use `.Cells(i, 4)` instead of `.Range(Cells(i, 4), Cells(i, 4)))`